# How to calculate "Relative Market Shares" Not Market Share using DAX formula

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a sample data of 5 companies (i.e. A,B,C,D,E) with market shares each of 40%,30%,20%,6%,4% in row. What is the relative market share for the leading company with the highest market share against the competitor (i.e. Next highest) company market share using DAX?

Below is an example of what am illustrating using Excel:

```
RMS of Company A = 40/30 = 1.33
RMS of Company B = 30/40 = 0.75
RMS of Company C = 20/40 = 0.50
RMS of Company D = 6/40 = 0.15
RMS of Company E = 4/40 = 0.10
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to calculate, and what data you're starting with. I think you should try to provide a more complete set of starting data and explain what you're trying to calculate more clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried to solve that as below:

First, I created a calculated column named "Ranked by share" to rank the companies according to the market share.

dax code is as below:

[image: dax code is as below]

Then, I created measure as below to calculate Relative share as per your requirements:

```
Relative market share = 

VAR leading_share = CALCULATE(MAX(Companies[Market Share]), all(Companies))

VAR competitor_share = calculate(VALUES(Companies[Market Share]), Companies[Ranked by Share] = 2, all(Companies))

VAR market_share = SUMX(Companies, Companies[Market Share])

Return
If(market_share < leading_share, divide(market_share,leading_share), divide(leading_share, competitor_share))
```

Finally, when I created table visual, the values are shown correctly as below:

Final result:

[image: Final result]